# ng test JavaScript heap out of memory in angular due to large mock data

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I am doing testing in angular 4 in my test cases i need large amount of data.
I dynamically require the json which is needed in my spec files.
These files are approximately 4 to 5 MB.

Here is some reference ...

```
  it('Multiple JSON:', () => {
    rdocList.forEach(element => {
      if (element.rdoc_id) {
        service.rdoc = require('../mock/' +
          element.rdoc_id +
          '.json');
        service.rdoc = new RDoc(service.rdoc);
        const storage = service.rdoc.descendants.filter({
          class_id: STORAGE_CLASS_IDS.ID
        });
        const clusterNode = storage[0].descendants.filter({
          class_id: STORAGE_CLASS_IDS.CLUSTERID
        });
        component.id = clusterNode[0].id;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  });
```

i have cleared the json in after each..

```
  afterEach(() => {
    service.rdoc = null;
    service = null;
  });
```

i get this issue

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, instead of a simple `ng test`, this worked:
`node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test`
where `8192` is your disered memory to allocate

Answer (score 1):

You can also first increase the memory usage of the node globally by running `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` followed by the `ng test` command.

Answer (score 0):

Move to npm location in this path - C:\Users*UserName*\AppData\Roaming\npm

try to changing **ng.cmd** to this:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
   "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
   @SETLOCAL
   @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
   node --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

change in **ngc.cmd** to:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
       "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js" %*
 ) ELSE (
       @SETLOCAL
       @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
       node --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js" %*
 )
```

Comment: I have done it still failed
My system has 32 GB RAM.
My question is how to manage GC while running testing